# Link Button to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a following GridView and my source code look like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ShopData.ascx.cs" Inherits="usercontrols.UsercontrolsShopData" %>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Export to csv</asp:LinkButton>
<br /> <br />
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewShopData" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />

</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT firstName as 'First Name',lastName as 'Last Name',employeeNumber as 'Employee Number',productID as 'Product Number' FROM ShopOrder where shopID=@pageid">
    <SelectParameters><asp:QueryStringParameter Name="pageid" QueryStringField="id"/></SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to make the first column values to link button that link to a url..how can i make this?

Comment: could you review your question and tell us where the question ?.

Comment: @ebram i want to make the first column of the gridview to linkbutton??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take template field for first column in your Grid view,and in that template field place Link button..

click on Link button->Link button Tasks->edit Data Bindings->Text=<%Eval("Your ColumnName")%

Answer (score 2):

In your gridview, set AutoGenerateColumn="False".  NExt, open the properties of the Gridview and convert the column to a template field.  Within item template, add the hyperlink control.  From here you can change the hyperlink control as you like.  To access the data from the column you can use eval (eg Text='<%# Eval("ColumnName", "Run") %>'

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a TemplateField. Please example code below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Your Header Here">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="<%# Bind(Text) %>" NavigateUrl='<%# "Your Link Here" %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```